# How to assign rows of np array according to rows of another array?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to build an array of points where each row depends on the corresponding row of a timestep array as in:

```
steps = 5
output = np.empty((steps, 3))
timesteps = np.linspace(0, 1, steps)

for i, step in enumerate(timesteps):
    output[i] = [sin(step), cos(step), 0]
```

With the expected output:

```
[[0.         1.         0.        ]
 [0.24740396 0.96891242 0.        ]
 [0.47942554 0.87758256 0.        ]
 [0.68163876 0.73168887 0.        ]
 [0.84147098 0.54030231 0.        ]]
```

How can I vectorize this operation?

---

I could assign each column independently like so:

```
out[:, 0] = np.sin(timesteps)
out[:, 1] = np.cos(timesteps)
out[:, 2] = 0
```

But I'd like to maintain a row-based approach for readability, if possible.

I was thinking of something like

```
output[:] = [np.sin(timesteps[:]), np.cos(timestep[:]), 0]
```

but obviously that doesn't work due to setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: The column assignment is the right way to do this.  I don't see how that makes things any less readable.

Comment: @TimRoberts I suppose it hides the point=row relation a bit, but yeah, not a big issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a numpy array in the following way:
 `np.array([np.sin(timesteps), np.cos(timesteps), [0]*len(timesteps)])`

However this sets sines as the first line, cosines as second and so on. To change them from being lines to being columns you can use the `transpose()` method also accesible via the `.T` attribute. Finally you'd get:

```
output = np.array([np.sin(timesteps), 
                   np.cos(timesteps), 
                   [0]*len(timesteps)]).transpose()
```

or

```
output = np.array([np.sin(timesteps), np.cos(timesteps), [0]*len(timesteps)]).T
```

I find this close enough to what you tried and guess this is ok about the "readability" concern. To check that this is indeed what you want:

```
import numpy as np

steps = 5
output = np.empty((steps, 3))
timesteps = np.linspace(0, 1, steps)

for i, step in enumerate(timesteps):
    output[i] = [np.sin(step), np.cos(step), 0]

output -= np.array([np.sin(timesteps), np.cos(timesteps), [0]*len(timesteps)]).transpose()

print(output)

> [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]
```

NB: `[0]*len(timesteps)` create a list of size `len(timesteps)` populated only with zeros

Answer (score 1):

I have something looks like this, can you try that ?

```
output[:] = [np.sin(timesteps[:]), np.cos(timestep[:]), 0]
```

Here is my solution:

```
import numpy as np
steps = 5
timesteps = np.linspace(0, 1, steps)

out=np.concatenate(([np.sin(timesteps)],[np.cos(timesteps)],[np.zeros(steps)]))

out=out.transpose()

out
array([[0.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.24740396, 0.96891242, 0.        ],
       [0.47942554, 0.87758256, 0.        ],
       [0.68163876, 0.73168887, 0.        ],
       [0.84147098, 0.54030231, 0.        ]])
```

I think this would be helpful, let me know any issue persists.